# highcharts issue on Android mobile device - the series are hidden when trying to prevent zoom action

Tags: highcharts

With the last version of Highcharts (3.0.2), there is an issue when trying to prevent zooming on the mobile device. After prevent, the series disappear from the chart.
In the below code can be seen that at the selection event of the chart it is prevented the  zoom action:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType:'x',
         events: {
            **selection: function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }**
        },
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled:false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    select:{
                        enabled:true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
},function(chart){
    chart.series[0].data[1].select();
});
```

The link for this test is http://jsfiddle.net/mihaelaCiocoiu/YAe9f/
and the link for load on the mobile is http://jsfiddle.net/m/pvb/

Please test on the Android mobile device in order to see this issue, by zooming in this example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it looks like a bug, so I reported to the developers https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1963